# Is it ok to add foried key user_id in user table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

for ex. I've 1 table which include teacher and student in user table and  1 teacher can add thier student in thier own How can I designed database ? and which one is better?

Here is 1st User table I think about add FK in to user table

```
id | email   | password | status | teacher_id (which refer to user_id)
1  | test@hot| 211231   | teacher| null
2  | t2@hot  | 12321    | student| 1
3  | t3@hot  | 121312   | student| 4
4  | t4@hot  | 313      | teacher| null
```

2nd  I think about sperate table into 2 tables

```
User
id | email   | password | status |
1  | test@hot| 211231   | teacher|
2  | t2@hot  | 12321    | student| 
3  | t3@hot  | 121312   | student| 
4  | t4@hot  | 313      | teacher|

Parents
id|teacher_id|student_id
1 | 1        |  2
2 | 4        |  3
```

NOTE:: I want 1 student can have only 1 teacher

Comment: is that possible student can take different course from different teacher? assume as a student i have started course db from teacher x. Once I complete the db course then im planning to take another course from different teacher. is this possible?

Comment: I will recommend you go for 2nd

Comment: oh yes it is I forgot to think about this thanks @Gaj

Comment: thank you . I'll try to use 2nd @RahulShrivastava

Comment: if the student can take more than one course from different teacher and you want history of student course details then 2nd option will be best one. If you don't want history and volume of users will be less then 1st option will be ok